# Which is a more efficient way to implement database sharding, PostgreSQL's foreign data wrappers? or multiple unrelated Postgres instances?

Tags: postgresql, performance

One way of implementing database sharding in postgresql 11 is partitioning the table and then using the foreign data wrapper to set it up so that the shards are running on their own containers. [read more here](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/development/enablement/database/doc/fdw-sharding.html)

what you get with this approach is that you only deal with one database.

another way of implementing database sharding in postgresql 11 is basically running multiple instances of postgres and handling all the sharding logic using code. for example, having an extra field in the data table titled sharding_id which we can use to decide which instance we need to query to retrieve the data. if the sharding id is 1 then query instance 1.

which of these approaches is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

This question would be as unanswerable as "what is better: PostgreSQL or Oracle", if sharding with foreign data wrappers were functional.

Alas, sharding by foreign data wrapper doesn't work yet. The missing link is that currently (v13), PostgreSQL cannot scan partitions that are foreign tables in parallel.